# How do I create and submit a form from a model inside a modal?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

In my app I have a page called products. In this page I display records form my database in a table.

Every row of the table has two buttons, to add and edit the record that is in the specific row.

The add and edit will be achieved by a form created by my model called Product.
This form will be displayed in a modal which will show when the add or edit button is clicked.

I have implemented the add and edit function, showing a form on a seperate page, not in a modal.

Below it is my models:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    year_manufactured = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]
```

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "products"
urlpatterns = [url(r'^products', views.ProductsView.as_view(), name="products"),
               url(r"^product/new", views.add_new_product_view, name="add_new_product"),
               url(r"^product/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/edit/", views.edit_product_view, name="edit_product")]
```

Below is my views:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, TemplateView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from . import models
from products.forms import AddNewProductForm, EditProductForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'products/products.html')


class ProductsView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "products"
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "products/products.html"
    form = AddNewProductForm()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["products"] = models.Product.objects.all().order_by("title")
        context["form"] = self.form
        return context


def add_new_product_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddNewProductForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return JsonResponse({'msg': 'Data saved'})
        else:
            print("ERROR FORM INVALID")
            return JsonResponse({'msg': 'ERROR FORM INVALID'})
    else:
        form = AddNewProductForm()
    return JsonResponse({'form': form})


def edit_product_view(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(models.Product, id=id)
    form = EditProductForm(instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditProductForm(request.POST, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return JsonResponse({'form': form})
        else:
            print("ERROR FORM INVALID")
    return JsonResponse({'form': form})
```

I have this on products.html:

```
{% extends "products/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}My Products{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

   <div class="container" id="my-products-table-container">
        <h2 class="text-left caption">Add, view and edit products</h2>
        <hr>
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-bordered" id="my-products-table">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <tr class="head-row">
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {% for product in products %}
                    <tr class="table-row">
                    <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.year_manufactured }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.manufacturer }}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNewProductModalForm">Add New product</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="findMyForm({{ product.pk }})">Update product</button></td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
            <!-- Modal Add New Product-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="addNewProductModalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewProductModalFormLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <form class="form" id="add_new_product_form">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addNewProductModalFormLabel">Add New Product</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                         {% csrf_token %}
                         {{ form.as_p }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addNewProduct()">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Modal Edit-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="editProductModalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editProductModalFormLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <form class="form"  id="edit_product_form" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editProductModalFormLabel">Edit Product</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                          <div id='showForm'></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit!">
                      </div>
                    </div>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>


<!-- JS Scripts  -->
<script src="{% static "products/js/addProduct.js" %}"></script>
<script>
    function findMyForm(productKey) {
        $('#editProductModalForm').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/product/' + productKey + '/edit/',
            success: function(res) {
            $("#showForm").html(res);
        }
        })}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

My JS scripts:

```
#addProduct.js
function addNewProduct(e) {
    var addNewProductForm = $("#add_new_product_form");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/product/new/',
        data: addNewProductForm.serialize(),
        success: function(res){
            alert(res['msg'])
        }
    })
}
```

I have updated my code to illustrate that I can successfully add a new product in my database. Also, I have been working on editing a product from my database.

When this button is pressed:

```
<button onclick="findMyForm({{ product.pk }})">Update product</button>
```

the modal that should contain the edit form appears, then the function findMyForm with the products.pk argument is called. After that an ajax get request is performed on the products edit url.

Based on my urls.py, the `edit_product_view` is called. 
This where I encounter the error that the EditProductForm is not serializable.

Also, huge thanks to Tico, for his continuous help.

Comment: I know a solution, but is different from modelform and instance, you could use ajax

Comment: Sure, I am planning on reading up on AJAX anyway. Care to elaborate ?

Comment: I don't have experience with AJAX so I am not sure, but you can send the id and return the instance

Comment: `Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation`: 'string'+ **+** 'string'. Concatenation is done with a single plus sign. And that's because you reference a template variable "product" which is local to the for loop above.

Comment: Between the two strings there is product.pk, but I guess it doesn't pass in the string concatenation.

Comment: Yes, see: `{% for product in products|slice:":10" %}` ... `{% endfor %}` in the `tbody` above. After endfor, no variable "product" exists anymore.

Comment: You need the js script inside the loop for this to work. But a better way is to pass the variable through the function:  findMyForm('/product/'+{{product.pk}}+'/edit/') and change the definition accordingly  Second the identation of JsonResponse in the edit_product_view is not correct. It should be outside the POST if. Third (this was not there in the beginning) why you want to put a Add new product in every product row? I think you don't need a button there (Do this outside the loop). Insteaad you need to bind your modal footer submit button to a update function.

Comment: Fourth: ajax for new data should have POST method. Also it should pass form data in a form of object  data:yourDataFromForm. Build this object using jquery and rendered form ids.

Comment: @Tico I have fixed the identation issue. can you give me an example of the ajax for the new product ?

Comment: Just checking if we are on the same page. You are able to open a modal see product data, edit that and save your edit?  Adding a new product is a different thing.  Or are you stuck in saving your edit?

Comment: @Tico I am focusing on the add new product first to get how it works and then I will deal with the edit.

On the add product, the modal is displayed but I suspect there is a problem with the csrf token, where is its proper place in the html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand what you want from the beggining. I assume that you want the user to see the products catalog then, when he clicks the update button from a particular product, you need to trigger the modal with a form with correct loaded data from that product.
So I base my answer in this assumption

First change needed, in your products_catalog.html, is from this :

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="{% url "simple_app:edit_product" product.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

to a button that triggers a function: `<button onclick="findMyForm()">Update product</button>`

Then you should add that modal snippet to the end of your products_catalog.html, except the launch button. You don't need that. Also add an empty div inside the modal body `<div id='showForm'></div>`.

Now the findMyForm function should do three things. Lauch the modal, pick up the correct form from the server and put the form on modal body.

```
findMyForm(){
//the name myModal should be ID, as jquery notation suggests.
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/product/'+{{product.pk}}+'/edit/',
    success: function(res){          
        $(#showForm).html(res)   
    }

})
```

GET is important here, so the call go into the right `if` of the view. So this should call your `edit_product_view`, acording to your url settings, and it should return the form you want. The form is picked up by the success callback on ajax and put inside our empty div in the modal body.

But there is still a big problem. Your view is rendering the template again from scratch, and you don't want that. So the trick is to use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/) instead of render to avoid reloading (well, it wont work with render anyway). So this part in your view:

```
return render(request, 'simple_app/edit_product.html', {'form': form})
```

should turn into (remember to import `from django.http import JsonResponse`):

```
return JsonResponse({'form': form})
```

See that you don't need edit_product.html any longer. The above procedure builds its content inside the modal dynamically in the product_catalog.html page.

Ok. Now you should be able to push a button in products catalog that will pop a modal with the form revelant to the product without reloading. Let's say you make changes and want to save (POST part of the view). Pattern is similar:

- You need a button inside your modal that will trigger a function `save_form`.
- Function will pick up new values from the form using jquery (use browser tools to find out what `{{form.as_p}}` renders to) and make an ajax POST call to `'/product/'+{{product.pk}}+'/edit/'` passing form data.
- Save data in your view and render index.html (or return JsonResponse({'res':'Your data was saved'}) and use ajax success callback to print that somewhere in your html).

EDIT:

To add a new product in a modal:

- Change your ProductView to pass an empty form to the products.html template.
- Minimal products.html is a modal (with default button). In the modal body you should render an empty form `{{form.as_p}}`. In the modal footer you should change the `<input>` to a `<button>` tag and link the button to a js function `addNew()`. Doing this will prevent default form submission.
- addNew is like this:

  ```
  addNew(){

    var data = {
       title: $('#title').val()  //Not sure if title is the correct selector. 
       description: $('#description').val() // get correct id with browser tools.
        ...
    }
    // Ajax calls view. Stringify format your js object to a json string.
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/product/new/',
      data:JSON.stringify(data),
      success: function(res){          
          alert(res['msg'])   
      }

    })

  }
  ```

The data formatting is the tricky part. I'm not sure how django forms expects the data to come. You probably have to print this in your view and manipulate before passing default validation functions. Let me know how this goes to you.

- Last you view is fine. Just change `return index(request)` to return `JsonResponse({'msg':'Data saved'})` to be sure you understand it works.

So your ADD NEW button is the default modal button. You press it and you get modal openned with an pre rendered empty form that comes from your class view. Then you have a ok BUTTON tied to a function. This function collects data from your form and send to server via Ajax, where you save data to your model. You can also send something back from the view (for other use cases) with JsonResponse, which will be picked up by success callback.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this works, you introduce extra requests just to render a form. For edit forms this is preferable as you don't know the form's initial data. For create, this extra request is unneeded and you can simply embed the form in the HTML. This also applies to related forms (like "edit this project" when a viewing a task in the project").

Comment: You are right about what I want to do, I have edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Melvyn You are absolutely right. I'm addicted to this pattern  :(  I'll edit my answer to take that in consideration and try again. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Melvyn I gave a second thought. The objective of my first request is to render the form with initial data. I cannot embed that in the HTML except if I put all data there from the beginning. I never intended to create an empty form. This is a edit form from the beginning. Not a create form.

Comment: OP's post has an add_product as well. Then again, scope of this question is kinda broad.

Comment: I have updated the views.py based on your answer to the best of my knowledge. The modal shows with the empty form, but then I hit submit I get a csrf error Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /product/new/.

I have included the {% csrf_token %}, isn't it enough ?

Comment: Nope.  Two options. you pass csrf manually in data object through ajax getting it from the page you've rendered. Option two: use @csrf_exempt decorator before your view. (from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt).

Comment: @Tico Not sure why, but when I used .serialized() to get the data from the form, the csrf error disappeared and the data was saved correctly.

Comment: For the update Button It is the same Pattern. Diffefence is that you need to render the first form using ajax to get initial data.

Comment: I have worked on the update functionality but I am stuck on passing the form from the edit_product_view.

Comment: Remove the link from the table to URL edit Review. Add a Button calling the function findmyform from my answer. You also need a second modal with an empty div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155201/discussion-between-giannisiordanou-and-tico).

Comment: I think I have addressed all your remarks in the code in my first post. Why the edit_product_view gives the error for the form ?

Comment: Hi! Sry delay. Intense weekend. So, you got it working? Error in form should be some formatting issue.